# How can I keep backup of last 1 year with only 100 backup copies, assuming backup runs every day?

Tags: ruby, algorithm, backup, logic

Assuming that I create a backup copy everyday and assuming that each backup is a single compressed file and contains the timestamp information in its filename.

Now, I want to write a daily running script that deletes older backups and keeps only 100 backups. However these 100 backups are spread over 1 year such that I still have a 1 year old copy, however I should have more copies of recent backups and lesser copies of older backups, i.e., at any given moment, the distance between two surviving consecutive backup copies keeps increasing as we go back in time.

Algorithm should also take the fact into account that it will be running once daily.

Also, is there a name for such algorithm - *`exponential range?`*, *`exponential distance?`*, *`non-linear backup expiry?`*, *`logarithmic something?`* anything?

If you're including code in your answer, I'd prefer Ruby (but not necessary, as I can manually transcompile it to Ruby if it is in another language).

Comment: Are you sure you need to code this yourself? A system like this is implemented in things like dirvish. It makes incremental backups (so you don't get the same files multiple times!), but at the same time has snapshots. It also lets define your expiration rules (like e.g. last 15 days, then each begin of the week for 4 weeks, then begin of the month, etc.) Not sure if this is what you want or not, so not an answer, but take a look? http://www.dirvish.org/   (i'm not affiliated in any way with dirvish, just a user).

Answer (score 3):

It sounds like you're thinking about something like the [Tower of Hanoi](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tower_of_Hanoi). Tape backup systems sometimes use this as a way to manage backup tapes. The Wikipedia article has several algorithms. It's often used as a programming exercise when you're learning recursion.

The game is based on moving a stack of different sized disks from one peg to another without ever putting a bigger disk on top of a smaller one. If you had five sets of tapes, labelled A through E, you'd end up moving them like this.

```
ABA
CABA
DABACABA
EABACABADABACABA
```

The set used least often is E, so if you start with E on January 1, you'll end up like this.

```
E                    Jan 1
ABA                  Jan 2-4
CABA                 Jan 5-8
DABACABA             Jan 9-16
EABACABADABACABA     Jan 17-Feb 1
```

The E set will be overwritten on Jan 17. Coverage will look like this on Jan 16.

```
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 
E               D           C     B  A
```

[A ruby program that solves the Tower of Hanoi puzzle](http://www.ruby-forum.com/topic/107700)

Comment: Wikipedia has nice tables of this: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Backup_rotation_scheme

Comment: @DataWraith: Duh. I didn't even think to look up backup rotations, just TOH.

Answer (score 1):

Let me describe a very simple algorithm that might work for you.

First of all assign everyday a global date counter, say number of days after Christ. You wanted ruby, so I show you how to do that in ruby (this shows that today is 734918th day)

```
require "Date"
Date.today - Date.new(0)
```

Now let me tell you which files you keep: You keep all files from the last 30 days, for the next 40 you keep every file with index divisible by 2, for the next 80 you keep every day with index divisible by 4, for the next 120 you keep every file with index divisible by 8 and for the rest 85/86 you keep every file with index divisible by 16. Thus as time moves on all you will need will be to check if you need to remove some of the stored files and will never need to show a file you already erased. Tell me if you need code for this logic, too.

Answer (score 1):

Keeping everything from the last two months and every sunday backup from the last year would result in a little over 100 files. Easy to explain, easy to execute and you know beforehand if a backup is there or not. 
Untested:

```
require 'date'
def bup_name(date=Date.today)
  "#{date.to_s}.bup"
end
def delete(fname)
  #todo: exception handling
  File.delete(fname) if File.exist?(fname)
end

today = Date.today
# make backup bupname(today)
delete( bup_name( today << 12 ))
two_months_ago = today << 2
delete( bup_name( two_months_ago )) unless two_months_ago.sunday?
```